# Published app shows "Cannot create PhoneAuthCredential without either verificationProof, sessionInfo, temporary proof, or enrollment ID. "

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

Firebase phone authentication works perfectly when the app is installed through android studio.
I have checked in the SHA which are included in the play Console (there are 3 pairs of SHA1 and SHA256 keys).

When I use the app installed from the play store. It sends the OTP but can not verify it.
**This is the error**

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create PhoneAuthCredential without either verificationProof, sessionInfo, temporary proof, or enrollment ID.

I am sure there is no problem in code as it ran perfectly in android studio mode. But still.. here is my code.
**GET OTP**

```
val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)
    .setPhoneNumber("+91$s") // Phone number to verify
    .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
    .setActivity(this) // Activity (for callback binding)
    .setCallbacks(mCallBack) // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
    .build()
    try{ Log.d("otpE", PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options).toString()) }
    catch(err:Exception) {
        Log.d("OTP ERROR", err.toString())
    }
```

**Verify OTP**

```
mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(object : OnCompleteListener<AuthResult?> {
                    override fun onComplete(task: Task<AuthResult?>) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
... 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your SHA1 key on playstore console as well.